# Escape does not clear notifications on Google Chrome and OS X

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, google-chrome, osx

**Situation**: Out of nowhere in chat:

```
@enderland - you are the most awesome person ever
```

**Results**: Hooray! I'm awesome. I have a little notification above my gravatar! Wooooo!

**Problem**: The Must.Make.All.Notifications.Go.Away person I am navigates to that tab. Ahah! Someone thinks I'm awesome! Now the notification goes away... right?

No, it doesn't. Which isn't a problem if it's year 2000 and I used a mouse, but it's 2013. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>(tab_number)</kbd> gets me there immediately.

But... the notification doesn't go away. It lingers... taunting me. I hear a voice calling, *use the mouse, I dare you. Or you will see the notification... always*.

So I click <kbd>Escape</kbd> on my keyboard. But alas, it does not work!

- Why does <kbd>Escape</kbd> not clear notifications on Google Chrome for Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)?

---

This also does not clear notifications for Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Escape does the trick I think?

Comment: @Bart Alas, this does not seem to be so (Chrome on OS:X) - all it does is move my cursor from the wonderful reply-textbox to nowhere.... which taunts me even more...

Comment: @enderland In that case please rephrase your question, because it *should* work, so this would be a bug report.

Comment: +1 for the all-so-very theatricalism.

Comment: Why would you want to clear that notification? Think about it: tough day at work? Coffee ran out? "@enderland - you are the most awesome person ever" should cheer you up!

Answer (score 3):

The bug (feature?) appears to be tied to where the cursor is focused.

On Firefox, <kbd>Esc</kbd> only appears to clear the chat notification icon if the cursor is located in the comment box.

I suspect that when you're <kbd>Cmd +</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd>  hopping around, the chat comment box is losing focus and it doesn't return there when you return to the tab.

You should be able to verify if this case by trying something similar to the following:

1. Have your [favorite chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) open in a tab.
2. Click somewhere on the chat room page, but outside of the chat comment box.
3. Switch to another tab, go merrily about your way.
4. Wait for someone to ping you in chat in order to tell you ["how awesome you are"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165906/194162)
5. Switch back to the chat room tab, and then use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move focus back to the chat comment box.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and hope for the chat notification to go away.

***Note:*** Depending upon where you click, you may have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> quite a few times in order to get back to the chat comment box.  On firefox, I found it fastest to just click in the main window above the chat comment box and it was quicker to shift the cursor focus.

Comment: Escape, even when my cursor is in the chat box, does not clear the notification (though it does move my cursor from there for some reason? not sure where. maybe that's the problem...)